# Divide the dataframe to the sum of each row

Tags: r

Let say I have a dataframe `A` (2 rows, 4 columns):

```
a   b   c   d
1   2   3   4
1   3   5   4
```

The first 2 columns are in the first group, the last 2 are in the second group. I want to divide this df by the row sums of each group. Basically I want something like this:

```
a     b     c     d
1/3   2/3   3/7   4/7
1/4   3/4   5/9   4/9
```

This is just a toy example. In my problem I have a lot of groups, not just 2.

Comment: How are your groups defined? Is it always every two adjacent columns? Or do you have, say, a list of vectors indicating the groups? Some pattern in the column names? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple way with a `for` loop. I'll assume you have a list of column indices for each group:

```
groups = list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4))

result = dd
for (g in groups) {
  result[g] = dd[g] / rowSums(dd[g])
}

result
#           a         b         c         d
# 1 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.4285714 0.5714286
# 2 0.2500000 0.7500000 0.5555556 0.4444444
```

You could also use `lapply` like this:

```
result2 = do.call(cbind, lapply(groups, function(g) dd[g] / rowSums(dd[g])))
```

---

Using this input data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "a   b   c   d
1   2   3   4
1   3   5   4", header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was the following. I wanted to crate pairs of columns by identifying even-number column positions (e.g., 2, 4, and 6). Then, I looped through each pair and handled the calculation in `lapply()`. In the final step, I combined all results using `as.data.frame()`. Note your data is called `mydf`.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(seq(from = 2, to = ncol(mydf), by = 2), function(x) {

            mydf[, (x-1):x] / rowSums(mydf[, (x-1):x])}

            ))

          a         b         c         d
1 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.4285714 0.5714286
2 0.2500000 0.7500000 0.5555556 0.4444444
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `g` define the groupings such that every column having the same value in `g` belongs to the same group.  Here we defined `g` to be successive pairs of columns in `DF` but if the groups had various sizes we would replace that with whatever definition were appropriate.

For each row in `DF` we split it by `g` using `ave` to apply `prop.table` to each component of the split.  For example, `prop.table(1:2)` gives `c(1/3, 2/3)`. 
We assign the result to matrix `mat`.  The last line converts `mat` to a data frame. We can omit this last line if a matrix is sufficient.

No packages are used.

```
g <- gl(ncol(DF)/2, 2)  # g = c(1, 1, 2, 2)

mat <- t(apply(DF, 1, function(x) ave(x, g, FUN = prop.table)))
as.data.frame(mat)
```

giving:

```
> prop
          a         b         c         d
1 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.4285714 0.5714286
2 0.2500000 0.7500000 0.5555556 0.4444444
```

If the columns always occur in pairs then

### Note

We used this as input:

```
DF <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L), b = 2:3, c = c(3L, 5L), d = c(4L, 
4L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```